# UpdatePanel stops working in Mozilla after adding an AsyncFileUpload control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In my web page, I have an [Ajax Control Toolkit `AsyncFileUpload`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) and a `DropDownList` inside an `UpdatePanel` with triggers.  If the user selects another item in the drop down, then it will show one `TextBox` below that drop down using the `UpdatePanel`.

Before putting the `AsyncFileUpload` on the page, it was working fine.  After adding the `AsyncFileUpload` to the page, the `UpdatePanel` has stopped working in response to the drop down.

Specifically, it still works fine in Internet Explorer, but it's not working in Mozilla.

How do I fix this error?

**JavaScript:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

       function uploadStarted() {
           $get("Img_Show").style.display = "none";
       }

       function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
           var Img_Show1 = $get("Img_Show");
           //  Img_Show.src = "images/loader.gif";
           Img_Show.style.cssText = "";
           var img = new Image();
           img.onload = function () {
               Img_Show.style.cssText = "height:200px;width:209px;float:left;margin-bottom:0;position:absolute;margin-right: 0;left:0px; top:0px;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;padding-top: 15px;";
               Img_Show.src = img.src;
           };
           img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + args.get_fileName();
       }

</script>
```

**Markup:**

```
<cc1:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" runat="server" ID="AsyncFileUpload1"
    ThrobberID="imgLoader" OnUploadedComplete="FileUploadComplete"  Width="100" OnClientUploadStarted = "uploadStarted"/>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlBusinessType" Style="width: 400px; left: 0px;" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBusinesstype_SelectedIndexChanged" 
             AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="designer" TabIndex="8"
             CausesValidation="True">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        </div>
            <span class="error">Error Class</span>
        </div>

        <asp:Panel ID="PanelBusinessType" runat="server">
            <div class="field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewBusinessType" runat="server" CssClass="textfield" TabIndex="9"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <span class="error"></span>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>   
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlBusinessType" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work in Firefox?  Do you see any errors in the Firebug console?  Does the async postback actually happen (you could put a breakpoint in your server-side code to check this)?

Comment: hello jadarnel27, thanks for your reply.it does not show any error in Firefox.i used javascript function for ASYNCHRONOUS File upload .this function only stopped working of update panel of drop down list .how do solve this error?

Comment: Not sure yet =)  Do you think you could [edit] your question to add your `UpdatePanel` markup (with everything that's inside it) *and* your JavaScript code for the asynchronous file upload?  You can notify me here in the comments when you're done.  Type "@jadarnel27" into the comment to make sure I get it.

Comment: my coded is added above.please check it and give your valuable comments.

Comment: It seems like this is the problem you're having: [UpdatePanel Breaks JQuery Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199130/updatepanel-breaks-jquery-script).  Basically, the controls are being re-created during the asyncpostback, so your JavaScript event handlers are no longer connected.